# Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator (MSKLC) did not "Build DLL and Setup Package"

Tags: keyboard-layout

Windows-supported keyboard layout for my native language is annoying and I tried to make some changes using MSKLC 1.4 on my Windows 10 laptop. After validating and testing, I selected **Build DLL and Setup Package** from the project menu.
It shows like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh28U.png)

When I pressed OK.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrh6U.png)

What should I do to fix this?